# objectify and etree elements

Tags: python, lxml

The module I've been writing works finestkind with the test data file, but totally moofs on the live data from flickrapi.

After days of frustration (see, I DO have a lot of nothing to do!) I think I found the problem, but I don't know the fix for it.

- Internal test data returns a type() of: `<type 'str'>`
- External test data returns a type() of: `<type 'str'>`  ## opening &
  reading external XML
- Live data returns a type() of: `<class

  'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element'>`

Beyond this point in the module, I use objectify.  Objectify parses `<type 'str'>` just fine, but it ***will not*** read the etree elements.  I *think* I need to convert the class 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' to str(), but haven't sussed that out yet.

The error I get from objectify.fromstring() is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Mirc\Python\Temp Files\test_lxml_2.py", line 101, in <module>
        Grp = objectify.fromstring(flickr.groups_getInfo(group_id=gid))
    File "lxml.objectify.pyx", line 1791, in lxml.objectify.fromstring (src\lxml\lxml.objectify.c:20904)
    File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 2994, in lxml.etree.fromstring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:63296)
    File "parser.pxi", line 1614, in lxml.etree._parseMemoryDocument (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:93607)
ValueError: can only parse strings
```

Please help before the boss turns loose those damn flying monkeys again!!!

```
import fileinput
from lxml import html, etree, objectify
import re
import time
import flickrapi


if '@N' in gid:
    try:
        if tst:
            Grp = objectify.fromstring(test_data)
        else:
            Grp = objectify.fromstring(flickr.groups_getInfo(group_id=gid))

        fErr = ''
        mn = Grp.xpath(u'//group')[0].attrib
        res = Grp.xpath(u'//restrictions')[0].attrib
        root = Grp.group

        gNSID = gid
        gAlias = ""
        err_tst = getattr(root, "not-there", "Error OK")
        gName = getattr(root, "name", "")
        Images = getattr(root, 'pool_count', (-1))
        Mbr = getattr(root, "members", (-1))
```

Comment: I don't see the error coming from `objectify.fromstring()` in your error stack. `root = objectify.XML(url)`? did you mean something like `root = objectify.XML(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())`?

Comment: Sorry, I posted the wrong error.  I've put the correct one in now, but the error is coming from  
 `Grp = objectify.fromstring(flickr.groups_getInfo(group_id=gid))`

Comment: Note that in the posted code `flickr` is a free variable.

Comment: Yes, in the actual code it's initialized as `flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to stop converting your live data to `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` objects before invoking the objectify api.

If that's impossible (which I doubt), you can render the xml back to a text representation with `lxml.etree.tostring`, then pass that to `etree.objectify.fromstring`.

Comment: Thank you! flickrapi was converting it to etree by default.  After digging about in the flickrapi source code I found a way to get it to output raw data instead of etree. For some reason `lxml.etree.tostring` wouldn't work - it kicked out a `Type 'Element' cannot be serialized.` error, but that's another topic.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think the "test_data" that you pass to *objectify.fromstring* is instansce of String IO , so you must read it first then objectify:

```
objectify.fromstring(test_data.read())
```